# How do I 'attach' objects to a page

Tags: web, screen

I am new to programming, so pardon my ignorance.

I am currently designing a website. However I have come across the problem of different screen dimensions. For example, when you zoom out of the page or see the web page on another screen, there's white space at the side of the page and you can clearly see where it ends.

If I where to zoom out of the google.co.uk web page, I would see the navigation bar at the top keep with the zooming out process. It doesn't keep the same size, it drags out.

How would I achieve this effect and what is it called? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
<div style='width: 100%; background: #ccc;display:inline-block'>Menu 1 | Menu 2</div>
```

CSS purists will probably insist you put this into a style page.